# Angular Routing and modules

Tags: angular

I have a module that imports another module. Both modules have a route path named 'listing' How does the routing merge if both modules have same routing name? It appears that the routes merge. In my situation the URL displayed showed one route while the actual page displayed was from the other module/route. Obviously to fix the routing issue I renamed the route paths to unique names but was curious as to what was actually occurring?

Comment: You should really only have one module define routing config

Comment: @wilusdaman if you've read the angular docs on routing you will see the intent of the Angilar team is actually the opposite of what you see claiming.  https://angular.io/guide/router Go the the bottom of the page where they talk about module imports and moving routes out of the app module into feature modules. It even described how the routes are merged together when importing modiles which is what the op is referencing.

Comment: I was going to point out how angularjs (what OP tagged the post) refers to angular 1.x and that your link is for modern angular, but reading through the angularjs developer guide and the JP style guide, they seem to back up what you're saying, so I retract my original statement :]

Comment: @wilusdaman thank you for the feedback. I did not mean to tag angularjs and have updated the post with angular tag.

Comment: @josh The angular router documentation was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here both the module names are the same so when you run the application then the route paths conflict. So you make a folder for both route.js files and drop both files in a different folder then change the paths. This will ensure your routes don't conflict.